# Sound not coming from headphones on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, sound, headphones, audio-jack

Sound plays out of speakers fine but not headphones. Also plays out of speakers when the headphones are plugged in. Audio still works on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

run these commands

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
echo options snd-hda-intel model=auto | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and try

```
sudo alsamixer
```

and try restarting the device,it should work. 
or there is a problem in your device audio jack check it

Comment: https://imgur.com/zqr2Hwn this is what came up. Audio still works fine on windows ten